# DSSP and HSSP: configure: error: Could not find a version of the library

Tags: c++, boost, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to compile [DSSP and HSSP](https://github.com/cmbi/hssp) in MinGW64 under Windows 10 and MSYS2.

I am seeing the following message:

```
pc_name@user_name MINGW64 ~/hssp
$ ./configure --verbose
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking whether make supports the include directive... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking for perl... perl
checking for cppcheck... no
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking for boostlib >= 1.54... yes
checking whether the Boost::Date_Time library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not find a version of the library!

pc_name@user_name MINGW64 ~/hssp
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: dont know, missing library , wrong version ... try Ubuntu https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/dssp.1.html

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE, what is the installation command?

Comment: sudo apt install <package>

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE, thanks a lot. Please, post the comments as an asnwer.

Comment: apt-cache dump | grep mkdssp ---> nothing ; apt-cache dump | grep dssp ----> Package: dssp ; apt-cache search dssp ---> dssp - protein secondary structure assignment based on 3D structure , its part "of pdb redo" I believe but not sure https://github.com/PDB-REDO/dssp/issues

Comment: Its not an answer to your question, dont know what is wrong with your boosy library see: https://github.com/cmbi/hssp/blob/master/m4/ax_boost_timer.m4#L98 ,  cannot find STRIDE source code or repo or binaries anywhere in the web though

Comment: Did you already build the dependency libzeep? I noticed it doesn't build out of the box with MinGW-w64