# How can I use STRIDE algoritm in Python?

Tags: python, biopython

```
from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import stride
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

# Load protein structure
parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure('protein', 'path/to/protein.pdb')

# Calculate secondary structure using STRIDE algorithm
ss, phi, psi = stride(structure[0]['A'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import stride
ImportError: cannot import name 'stride' from 'Bio.PDB.Polypeptide' (/home/runner/STRIDE-Algorithm/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Polypeptide.py)
```

What is missing here?

Comment: I have gone through the repo of biopython, itseems there is no package called `stride` from `Bio.PDB.Polypeptide`. but found out for calculating secondary structure there is another package present in the same repo called `secondary_structure_fraction` which is under  `Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam`, do try and let know if this works. Thanks

Comment: if you have a working version of DSSP try https://biopython.org/docs/1.81/api/Bio.PDB.DSSP.html

Comment: pymol has his own algho : https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Dss

Comment: chimera hai its own too : https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/midas/ksdssp.html

Comment: if you have a working copy of STRIDE : https://github.com/MDAnalysis/pystride not sure it works and what does the package does, check it before running

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE, these are Python-bindings, not the actual algorithm packages.

Comment: @pippo1980ONSTRIKE, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585221/dssp-and-hssp-configure-error-could-not-find-a-version-of-the-library

Comment: @user366312 if you have a working version of DSSP try biopython.org/docs/1.81/api/Bio.PDB.DSSP.html .... traduced  if you have a working version of DSSP could use these python bindings https://biopython.org/docs/1.81/api/Bio.PDB.DSSP.html

Comment: I see .... ....